# Create an enterprise build show strange error

Tags: xcode, testflight

I am trying to create a build for `enterprise` , we have a company developer account at `Apple` .

When i choose the enterprise options i get :

```
to save for enterprise deployment you need to add an apple id account that is enrolled in the iOS developer program,for the development team xyzxyz
```

Trying to set our Apple ID ,gives a message says this one is already exist .

So, in general, whats the different between adhoc and enterprise, and why can't i use the second?
(do i have to ? we need to share our build with test flight )

Answer (score 0):

From your description I think you need to register for enterprise [distribution](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/).

If you sign the app for Ad Hoc distribution you will only be able to install the app on the devices that you have registered with developer [portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceList.action).